# Lift and drag force measurement in a flume

Tags: fluid-mechanics

I'm trying a test a hydrofoil in a low Reynolds flume, but struggling to find a way to mount the hydrofoil in the flume and measure the lift and drag force.

I have some idea of using a load cell but not sure how to set it up and connect it with to hydrofoil, as the hydrofoil span across the width of the flume.

Answer (score 0):

If practical install a shaft through the hydrofoil passing through its center of pressure into the walls of the flume continuing into two support donut load sensors. This way you can measure the lift and drag.

Or you can use four pancake sensors two on each side. One set for lift, the other for drag.

You can find the center of pressure of the hydrofoil by trial and error or if it comes with a chart look up the chart.

I add a link to airfoils here which can be helpful. [center of pressure airfoil](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/19399/9265)

Answer (score 0):

We did this for wind tunnels, with side supports or vertical supports from beneath or above depending what the shape was and what was most convenient.

Do remember to run some tests to see the loads applied to the supports when the model being tested is absent so those values can be removed from the results.

Answer (score 0):

They can get a bit complicated and expensive, so you really need to write down about ten pages of specifications on the test flume geometry, the test battery, the hydrofoil geometries, and the data you want.

[image]